# Pandas, copy rows whose names are repeated N times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Example data:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'file': ['file1','file1','file1','file2','file2','file2','file3','file3','file4'],
    'prop1': [True,False,True,False,False,False,True,False,False],
    'prop2': [False,False,False,False,True,False,False,True,False],
    'prop3': [False,True,False,True,False,True,False,False,True]
})
```

I need to copy rows whose 'file' repeat 3 times, to get something like this:

```
file    prop1   prop2   prop3
0   file1   True    False   False
1   file1   False   False   True
2   file1   True    False   False
3   file2   False   False   True
4   file2   False   True    False
5   file2   False   False   True
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for Series with same size like column, so possible filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df1[df1.groupby('file')['file'].transform('size') == 3]
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df1.groupby('file')['file'].transform('size'))
0    3
1    3
2    3
3    3
4    3
5    3
6    2
7    2
8    1
Name: file, dtype: int64
```

Or use [`filtration`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#filtration):

```
df = df1.groupby('file').filter(lambda x: len(x) == 3)
```

Or use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df = df1[df1['file'].map(df['file'].value_counts()) == 3]
```

---

```
print (df)
    file  prop1  prop2  prop3
0  file1   True  False  False
1  file1  False  False   True
2  file1   True  False  False
3  file2  False  False   True
4  file2  False   True  False
5  file2  False  False   True
```

Answer (score 3):

You could `groupby` the `file` name, transform with the `size` and use the result to index the dataframe:

```
df1[df1.groupby('file').prop1.transform('size').eq(3)]

   file   prop1  prop2  prop3
0  file1   True  False  False
1  file1  False  False   True
2  file1   True  False  False
3  file2  False  False   True
4  file2  False   True  False
5  file2  False  False   True
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC `transform`

```
df=df1[df1.groupby('file')['file'].transform('count').eq(3)].copy() # esure you do not have copy warning for future modify .
    file  prop1  prop2  prop3
0  file1   True  False  False
1  file1  False  False   True
2  file1   True  False  False
3  file2  False  False   True
4  file2  False   True  False
5  file2  False  False   True
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use [DataFrame.set_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
new_df=df1.set_index('file').loc[df1.groupby('file').size().eq(3)]
print(new_df)
```

---

```
     prop1  prop2  prop3
file                      
file1   True  False  False
file1  False  False   True
file1   True  False  False
file2  False  False   True
file2  False   True  False
file2  False  False   True
```